# Show text on a label for a specific time

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to show a text in a label for a particular time so I did a search on google and I found these two solutions :

***The first solution is :***

```
public void InfoLabel(string value)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action<string>(InfoLabel), new object[] { value });
        return;
    }
    barStaticItem3.Caption = value;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        System.Timers.Timer timer = 
                                new System.Timers.Timer(3000) { Enabled = true };
        timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) =>
        {
            this.InfoLabel(string.Empty);
            timer.Dispose();
        };
    }
}
```

***The second solution :***

```
private void ShowTextForParticularTime(String caption)
{
    Timer t = new Timer { Interval = 5000, Enabled = true};
    t.Tick += (sender, args) => OnTimerEvent(sender, args, caption);  
}

private void OnTimerEvent(object sender, EventArgs e, String caption)
{
    barStaticItem3.Caption = caption;
}
```

Could you please tell me the deffrence between the two solutions, and why we use this symbole "=>" , also I understood nothing from this line :

```
if (InvokeRequired)
{
    this.Invoke(new Action<string>(InfoLabel), new object[] { value });
    return;
}
```

Comment: Which tech are you using Asp.Net, WinForms or WPF?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'll edit my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, there is a good amount to explain here.

There is no major differences between the two options you have shown. The reason they look different is because the first id declaring a delegate method (lambda expression) inside the public method, while the second is just creating an event handler. They do almost the exact same thing. Infact you can see that in the delegate method you have the tradition event handler prameters (object sender, EventArgs e). Personally I prefer the second solution because it looks cleaner to me.

Invoke Required is used to handle threading. In C# errors will be thrown if a thread that didn't create a visual object tries to alter the visual object. To get around this we make a call to the thread that created the visual object by calling "Invoke". The "InvokeRequired" property just tells us if the current thread did not create the visual object. You should always use this when you are threading or making delegate methods (because you can't control the thread that runs them.)

I hope this brief explanation helps. Comment if it is unclear

Comment: Okey thanks a lot .. I still  have some ambiguity to understand this, but I got the idea, I have only one more question that the second solution shows the string after the time I specified but I want to show the string for the time I specified than it disappear and solution 1 works for me.

Comment: answered that problem on the other answer. They were so similar I got confused :)

Answer (score 2):

In WinForms and WPF, the UI can only be updated from the thread that created the control in question.  These two approach show two ways to update your UI from a different thread.

The first approach manually checks if the code is running on a different thread and, if it is, marshals the call to the UI thread.

The second approach uses an event, leaving the details of marshaling to .NET

The symbol => represents a [lamda expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function).  You can think of it much like a function pointer (though sometimes it is really something called an [expression tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) behind the scenes).  Essentially, it creates a variable that points to code that can be called by referencing that variable.

Either approach should work fine.  Personally I prefer the second approach because it allows the framework to handle more of the plumbing work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, for me I used the first solution because the second do the opposite work I want it shows the string after the time I specified but the first shows the string for the time I specified.

Comment: Ah, there is a simple fix to this. The tick function occurs after the time specified. If you want the caption to start visible, set it when you open the form or create the caption, and make the OnTimer event set it to String.Empty